# How to prove that a simple NFA is minimal, without any algorithm?

Tags: automata, regular-language

First, I will present the question I was doing:

We will define $p(L)$ to be the minimal natural number so that a language L fulfill the pumping lemma.
We will also define $n(L)$ to be the minimal NFA (NFA with a minimal number of states) that accepts L.

Find a regular language so that $p(L)<n(L)$.

My solution: I will define $L$={$ab$,$cd$}, and ∑={$a,b,c,d$}.
The length of the longest word at L is 2 so it is easy to tell that $p(L)=3$.
Now, I don't think that exists a NFA with less states for $L$ then those two:

[image]

But I don't know how to formally prove that.
Maybe there is a possible connection here to an equivalent classes and DFA which might help?
Note: I am not allowed to use any algorithm for finding minimal automata (but I am allowed to use facts about equivalent classes and DFA).

Comment: Hint: The Myhill-Nerode theorem defines an equivalence relation $\sim_L$ on $\Sigma^*$ which has finitely many equivalence classes iff $L$ is regular; and if $L$ *is* regular, the number of equivalence classes = the number of states in a minimal FA accepting $L$.

Comment: Ok, but I know that this theorem is about NFA, not about DFA. How can this help me at NFA?

Comment: It doesn't matter: the proof of Myhill-Nerode can be adapted to NFAs so as to show that the number of equivalence classes of $\sim_L\le$ number of states of any NFA accepting $L$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem. Actually i mistated the corollary of the theorem, it's $\le$ not $=$: as stated above for NFAs, the number of equivalence classes $\le$ number of states in any DFA accepting $L$, thus $\le$ # of states in a DFA with minimal number of states. But as mentioned, the same holds for NFAs. The wikipedia article gives a proof for DFAs.

Comment: And what if I have L={ε}? I have a NFA with one state that accept this language, but there are at least two equivalent classes at L (you can take the words $ε$ and $a$ and seperate them, when the alphabet is ${a}$).

Comment: Good catch: $L = \{\varepsilon\}$ might just be a special case. The minimal DFA accepting that $L$ has two states, and $p(L) = 1$. Thinking about this more, I doubt what I said about an NFA version of M-N theorem. It's true only for NFAs that have all transitions on all symbols. Call such an NFA "full". You can convert an NFA $N$ which lacks some transitions to a full NFA $N'$ by adding one state, a nonaccepting "sink" state $q_s$: if $q$ lacks a transition on $\sigma$ in $M$, add a transition $q\stackrel{\sigma}\to q_s$. So the full version of your machine will have $5$ states. <cont>

Comment: <cont> Unless I'm mistaken, the relation $\sim_L$ for your two-string language has $5$ equivalence classes (omitting curly braces): $\varepsilon$, $a$, $c$, $ab\sim_L bd$, and $b\sim_L d \sim_L $ any $x\notin L$.